# Fade out divs one at a time using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, fadeout

I have this function that fades out each div apart from the one that has been clicked on. At the moment they all fade out at the same time, but I would like them to fade out one at a time.

I would also like the divs to fade out in a random order so extra points to anyone who can tell me how!

```
$(".grid-item").click(function () {

  var selected = this;

  $('.grid > div').not(selected).each(function(i) {
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: where are the extra points .. lol :D

Comment: @TusharRaj, I always wonder the same! Or when they say *bonus* to whoever can also do xyz. What bonus? Where? :)

Comment: Try this -> `$('.grid > div').not(selected).each().delay(200).fadeTo(200,function () {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
 });`

Comment: True ..LOL Again :D @AmmarCSE

Answer (score 0):

This is logic you can use: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27660144/1414562)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid-item").click(function () {
        var selected = this;
        var queue = $.Deferred().resolve(); // create an empty queue
        $('.grid > div').not(selected).get().forEach(function (div) {
            queue = queue.then(function () {
                return $(div).fadeTo(200, 0).promise();
            })
        });
    });
});
```

**DEMO** with bonus [randomizing array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/1414562): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scdsumc4/)

Comment: Thanks... this works brilliantly. Apart from it doesn't fade in a random order. How would you add this feature?

Comment: @GusPowell But in jsFiddle, it is fading out in random order: http://jsfiddle.net/scdsumc4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected;

var fader = function() {
    $('.grid > div').not(selected).not(':hidden').first().fadeOut(200, fader);
};

$(".grid-item").click(function () {
    selected = this;
    fader();
});
```

For the randomness, have a look at:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/

Please give me the bonus points.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit lengthy, but I like it because it uses a recursive function to randomize the delay of the fades:

```js
var doms = [];
var randos = [];
var index = 0;

$(".grid-item").click(function () {
    var selected = $(this);
    doms = $('.grid > div').not(selected);
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * doms.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < doms.length; i++)
    {
        while (randos.indexOf(num) > -1)
        {
            num = Math.floor(Math.random() * doms.length);
        }
        randos.push(num);
    }
    fadeout();
})

window.fadeout = function () {
    if (doms.length > 0) {
        var random = $(doms.get(randos[index]));
        $(random).delay(200 * index).fadeTo(200, 0, function () {
            $(random).css("visibility", "hidden");
        });
        doms = doms.not(random);
        index++;
        fadeout();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">hello</div>
    <div class="grid-item">how</div>
    <div class="grid-item">are</div>
    <div class="grid-item">you</div>
    <div class="grid-item">today</div>
</div>
```