# understanding how $.promise works similar to transitionEnd

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, promise

I was just messing around on the documentation page of `jQuery.promise()` and came across the following peice of code :

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("p").append("Started...");

    $("div").each(function (i) {
        $(this).fadeIn().fadeOut(1000 * (i + 1));
    });

   $("div").promise().done(function () {
        $("p").append(" Finished! ");
    }); 
});
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhndof4j/)

Now I do understand that $.defer in jQuery assists in Asynchronous programming, also I understand that $.done and $.fail are part of the $promise object .

I have read an interesting article **[HERE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/)**. There are a few good examples of how $.defer can be used to monitor css-3 transitions.

However in the fiddle example I provide, I fail to understand how $.promise picks up the fact that the transition is complete. How does promise pick up that that fadeout() is complete?

How does the below piece of code really work?

```
$("div").promise().done(function () {
            $("p").append(" Finished! ");
        });
```

How is promise really working here? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Because all animations on matched element in set (`$('div')`) are put by default in  `fx` queue, using for each animation a deferred object, which is resolved on animation complete. Once queue is empty, and all the deferred objects in queueHooks are resolved, the promise `done()` callback is fired.

Comment: I added `promise` tag (and animation but...) because there is some specialists of promise on SO who could better explain it i guess

Comment: As a side note, this would be better way to handle animations sequentially: http://jsfiddle.net/xn9xzyx6/   See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27660144/1414562

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, jQuery creates a queue of Deferred objects on each object returned by the `$("div")` selector (these are visible using the `.data()` function).
When you add some CSS animations to the divs with jQuery functions such as `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`, it creates Deferred objects that are appended to each individual div queues.
Using`$("div").promise().done()` on the parent collection allows to check if all of the children Deferred object queues are empty (jQuery will iterate on the children elements).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't delved into the jQuery source, but here's my understanding.

$.promise returns a Promise which completes once all actions of a certain type have ended. By default, the 'type' is `fx` ([source](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)).
When the `fx` queue is empty, the promise will resolve.

In your fiddle, you call `fadeIn()`, which adds the animation to the `fx` queue. (`$.fadeIn()` has `queue: true` by default.) `$.fadeOut` does the same.

When the queue is empty, the promise will resolve. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/zhndof4j/4/) would support that. (Queue is 'inprogress' whilst the animations are running, but empty 100ms later.)
[A slightly more convoluted fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/zhndof4j/5/) - notice how the promise completes when we clear the `fx` queue using `$(el).queue('fx',[]);`?